# From Future<List<String>> to List<String> for API calls to use in regular functions/scaffold

Tags: list, flutter, dart, widget

I'm using the TMDb API to get image urls to display. I am able to get the image urls and display them on the console. But then when I try to create a method and loop through for each of the items in the list it keeps returning empty (i checked with print).

Edit: Both methods are inside the same class and literally right below each other.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
List<String> popularMovie = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getJsonData();
  }

  //GET POPULAR MOVIE INFO WITH API
  Future<List> getJsonData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(popularURL),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    );


    var popularMovieData = json.decode(response.body);
    var placeholder = popularMovieData['results'];


    //get a list of images only
    for(var item in placeholder) {
      popularMovie.add(item['poster_path']);
   }
    print(popularMovie.length); //20
    print(popularMovie); //prints [imgURL, imageURL, ...]
    return popularMovie;

  } //end of popular movie api function
```

Below is the method that is suppose to loop through list items

```
//method to iterate through each item and get the image url to display image
  List<Widget> popularMovies() {
    List<Widget> popularMovieList = new List();

  for(var item in popularMovie) { //this is empty
    var popularMovieItem = Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Container(
      width: 250,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
            spreadRadius: 4,
            blurRadius: 4,
          ),
        ]
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2 - 20,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15),),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${item}'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
  popularMovieList.add(popularMovieItem);
    }
    return popularMovieList;
  }
```

And finally, I'd like to display all the movies on my page as

```
children:popularMovies(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! It is super easy with setState so if anyone needs a solution to convert a 
`Future<List<String>> to List<String>` and then use it as a normal List inside the scaffold here's what I did:

First, declare your list variable:

```
List<String> popularMovie = List<String>(); //declare a list inside the class
```

Then do your http call and assign the 'list of items you want' to your previously declared list variable 'inside setState'

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getJsonData();
  }

  //GET POPULAR MOVIE INFO WITH API
  Future<List<String>> getJsonData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(popularURL),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    );

    setState(() { //only get the first 10 movie images
      var popularMovieData = json.decode(response.body);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        popularMovie.add(popularMovieData['results'][i]['poster_path']);      
      }
      print(popularMovie);
    });

  } //end of popular movie api function
```

Then I created a method to create a widget to display each image which is the same as the method I created in my original post that starts like this:

```
List<Widget> popularMovies() {
```

And finally, I wanted to display it this way(which you can do however you want to):

```
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: popularMovies(), //display all images in a horizontal row
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

And you're done!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `getJsonData` is an async function, you need to use a `FutureBuider` or else instead of returning `popularMovie` you need to call `setState`

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: getJsonData,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Press button to start.');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

Comment: If my answer helped you can vote and mark as the correct answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to APIs. Before I mark it as my answer I just wanted to clear something out for myself. Instead of outputting texts I'm trying to output widgets (cards) to display. I'm guessing I'll be creating a list and pushing each widget into my list if ConnectionState.done has no error? will I be able to use that list inside another function or say my scaffold that way if I declare the list globally inside the class?

Comment: Edit: I figured it out with setState. Future Builder was a little confusing to me as I wasn't sure how to get the List and use it normally with other functions/inside the builder